# enable-migrations error : project failed to build

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using ASP.NET MVC4 with EF4.3

Running `Enable-Migrations` from PM Console

> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The project 'MyProj'
>   failed to build. The project 'MyProj' failed to build.

The project builds (control-shift-B)

Is there any way to get more detail on this error to diagnose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had run this earlier, on a project where there was no dbContext.  This created a migrations Configuration class that said "fill in the name of the class", which was failing to build.

This was causing one of my projects to silently fail to compile.

Removing the Configuration class solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

This can also happen if you are building a 64-bit application. Switch to "Any CPU", at least temporarily while building the migrations, and the problem may go away. This is just *one* thing that can cause that error, though.

Answer (score 3):

Executing "Enable-Migrations" from the package manager console requires a reference to a specific DbContext. For example

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName myMvcApp.Web.Infrastructure.ContextDb
```

You do not need to install a 3rd party assembly or any other assembly other than the EntityFramework 4.3+ (the command above is for EF 5.0.  This is not a well documented but essential feature of the EF.

Answer (score 2):

Let's be clear. This error is a confusing one because the message suggests that the project won't build whereas it clearly does compile in Visual Studio.

It happened to me after refactoring namespaces for ApplicationDbContext and other security classes to match the folder structure from

```
namespace {projectname}.Models
```

to

```
namespace {projectname}.Models.Account
```

Reverting this namespace refactoring fixed the issue.

Sometimes, rarely, ReSharper is not your friend.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had errors in my project. I have cleared all other errors in my project.
Then it works well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a message in the Visual Studio output window that made much more sense.

> PosmasterDBContext' does not contain a definition for 'Products' and
> no extension method 'Products' accepting a first argument of type
> 'PosmasterDBContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly reference?)

I knew right away that somewhere in my code, I changed **Products** to **Product**

Once I reverted it to **Products**, the error disappeared.